# Pass string to method send email

Tags: javascript, vue.js

https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-component-for-social-sharing-of-links/

I want to pass Strings (`subject`,`mailTo`,`Body`) but i don't know how?

```
<a class="gmail" @click="emailLink(url, {subject, body})">
<script>

import Email from '@/components/Email';
import objectToGetParams from '../utils/objectToGetParams';
import 'vue-awesome/icons/envelope-square';

export default {
   name: 'newComponent',
   components: {
      Email
    },

     methods: {
      emailLink(url, { subject, body, mailTo }) {
        window.location.href =
          'mailto:' + mailTo +
            objectToGetParams({
              subject,
              body: body || url,
            },

          '__blank',
        );  
      },   
    },

data: () => ({
    isActive: false,
    mySub   :"test123@test.com",
  }),
};
</script>
```

*thank you for edit! At smartPhone it is not easy.
But now i'm at pc.*

**the question is how can i pass some String Parameters to the function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't need a click handler. Just a straighforward `href` should do.

```
<a 
    class="gmail" 
    :href="'mailto:' + emailAddress + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body"
/>
```

You'll need to URL encode those strings if they're not already in that format.

Comment: Oh ok so easy ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get your question, but coming from Stephen Thomas answer I'd like to offer you another way of generating a string from data in VueJS.

You could also use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), this will have two advantages:

1. Process `url` only when `id` changes.
2. Increase template readability.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    id: 15
  },
  computed: {
    url () {
      return "https://api.example.com/resources/" + this.id
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <a :href="url">Resource {{ id }}</a>
</div>
```